# How to setup 'starflut' on flutter windows platform

Tags: python, flutter, dart

I need help to set up 'starflut' flutter windows platform for using python code ,
I downloaded this package [Require files.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GdiQqoQB8jlwafW34URahf4SpWh3-Pcx/view?usp=sharing) and this is my code then I tried to run it as it is and this is the errors

```
Restarted application in 413ms.
flutter: sqflite_common_ffi
flutter: docPath =
flutter: resPath = D:\Flutter\juniorproject\build\windows\runner\Debug
flutter: -1  1   load library error[126], try[C:\srplab/libs64/star_python36.dll]    6
flutter: -1  1   load library error[126], try[D:\Flutter\juniorproject\build\windows\runner\Debug/star_python36.dll]    6
flutter: -1  1   load library error[126], try[C:\srplab/libs64/star_python36.pyd]    6
flutter: -1  1   load library error[126], try[D:\Flutter\juniorproject\build\windows\runner\Debug/star_python36.pyd]    6
flutter: -1  1   load library error[126], try[C:\srplab/libs64/star_python36.so]    6
flutter: -1  1   load library error[126], try[D:\Flutter\juniorproject\build\windows\runner\Debug/star_python36.so]    6
flutter: -1  1   load library [D:\Flutter\juniorproject\build\windows\runner\Debug/star_python36.so] error....[126]   6
flutter: -1  4   [warn(1):(vsopenapi.cpp:38510):tm(20:11:11)]Script Error : interface not found   1
flutter: initRaw = false
flutter: -1  3   [warn(1):(skeletonproc_module:47599):tm(20:11:11)]load library [python27.dll] error....   1
flutter: -1  4   [warn(1):(vsopenapi.cpp:38376):tm(20:11:11)]Script Error : interface not found   1
flutter: loadRawModule = false
flutter: -1  4   [warn(1):(vsopenapi.cpp:24651):tm(20:11:11)]Script Error : interface not found   1
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String?' in type cast
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      StarServiceClass.importRawContext
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _MyAppState.initPlatformState
<asynchronous suspension>
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
assets:
   - assets/
   - assets/starfiles/
dependencies:
starflut: ^0.9.5
```

Comment: try flutter pub get and reopen your editor

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `pubspec.yaml` shoud be like this:

```
 assets:
   - assets/
   - assets/starfiles/
 dependencies:
   starflut: ^0.9.5
```

Otherwise, follow this steps:
1 run flutter clean
2 step-by-step with starflut documentation in GitHub repository [website](https://github.com/srplab/starcore_for_flutter)